# Stack 3 font awesome icons

Tags: svg, icons, font-awesome, glyphicons

I'm trying to stack 3 icons from font awesome into next to each other. See [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8Y45.png) for reference. I know font awesome has a stack class but that seems to have only 2 icon stacks and right on top of each other. Also I would like the individual icons to have a background in the area of the screen so that those areas are clipped and dont overlap.
Should I create a new svg and use that or is going the css route worth the effort.
Thanks

Comment: I have stack a bit of stuff recently (always 3 icons) and generally like the approach of re-using what is there instead of re-inventing. Youe q definitely makes a nice example for my collection, so I will take that challenge. But I'm afraid it will be a few days before I can spent any time with it :((  Have bookmarked the q and will kep you posted about result ;-)

Comment: Sounds great. Thanks for your time MBaas. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a new SVG is your best option.

Referring to your image, noting that FontAwesome icons are transparent, you would not be able to stack the fa-laptop in front of the fa-desktop and fa-mobile icons without them being visible through the laptop's screen.

Here is a demo to stack them with CSS and some absolute positioning to show you what I mean;
https://jsfiddle.net/k3en9L4m/

```
span.stack{
   position: relative;   
}
span.stack i{
   position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Thats what I was thinking too. I got it to work with a little bit of css. But I was wondering how to fill in the gaps. Is there a way to edit the font awesome icon so its not transparent?Or maybe fill in the gaps with absolute divs. But then again, seems like a lot of work for something simple.

Comment: I had to finally gave in and used an SVG because of CSS issues. But I did find a way to upload your own SVG as a font on fontello.com. Really useful website for font icons. Leaving this here for anyone who needs it.

Comment: Yes, and nice work on using Fontello.com its a great service.